# What would be the right ZMQ Pattern?

Tags: go, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to build a ZeroMQ pattern where,

1. There can be many clients connecting to a single server endpoint
2. Server will distribute incoming client tasks to available workers (will be mapped to the number of cores on the server)
3. These tasks are long running (in hours) and need to perform a lot of local I/O
4. During each task execution (iteration) there will be data/messages (potentially in order of `[GB]`s) sent back and forth between the client and the server worker
5. Client and server workers need to know if there are failures/errors on the peer side, so that they can recover (retry) or shutdown gracefully and try later

Based on the above, I presume that the `ROUTER/DEALER` pattern would be useful. `PUB/SUB` is discarded as I need to know if the peer fails.

I tried using various combinations of the `ROUTER/DEALER` pattern but I am unable to ensure that multiple messages from a client reach the same worker within an iteration. I understand that I need to implement a broker/forwarder/device that routes the incoming messages to the right recipient/handler/worker. But I am unable to map the frontend and backend sockets in the broker. I am looking at MajorDomo pattern, but I guess there has to be a simpler broker model that could just route the messages to the assigned worker. (not really get into services)

I am looking for some examples, if there are any or any guidance on what I may be missing. I am trying to build this in Golang.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"What would be **the right** ZMQ Pattern?"*

Based on the complex composition of all the requirements posted under items 1 - 5, I dare to say, ***The Right*** would be *NOT* to use *a single one* of the standard, built-in, ZeroMQ trivial primitive Communication Archetype Patterns, but to rather create a multi-layered application-specific composition of a ( M + N + 1 hot-standby robust-enough?) (self-resilient?) Signalling-Messaging infrastructure, that covers all your current ( and possibly extensible for any future one ) application-level requirements, like depicted here for a way simpler [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) use-case, where but a trivial remote-SigKILL was implemented.

[image]

Yes, the best would be to create ( and maintain ) your own formalised signalling, that the application level can handle and interact across -- like the heart-beating for detecting dead-worker(s) + permitting to re-instate such failed jobs right on-detected failures (most probably re-located and/or re-scheduled to take place & respective resources not statically pre-mapped, but where physically most feasible at the re-instating moment of time - so even more telemetry signalling will help you decide about the re-instating of the such failed micro-jobs).

ZeroMQ is a fabulous framework right for such complex signalling and messaging hierarchies, so your System Architect's imagination is the only ceiling in this concept.

ZeroMQ will take the rest and do all the hard work nice and easily.